# Creating slanted div's and aligning them horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement the following design in HTML. As of now I have added divs with slanted edges.

[image]

But, I have to make this div align based on other div's of same kind in the web page. Now, I'm trying to position the div's in such a way that the slanting on top and bottom seems on a line for both the div's in side by side. I need to know how to position these div's to achieve the mockup UI. Any suggestions or help is most welcome.

Tried code

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dataWrapper {
  margin: 5% 0;
  padding: 100px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.dataWrapper:before,
.dataWrapper:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: grey;
  z-index: -1;
}

.dataWrapper:before {
  top: -40px;
  transform: skew(0, -3deg);
}

.dataWrapper:after {
  bottom: -40px;
  transform: skew(0, -3deg);
}

.leftDiv {
  width: 49.5%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: grey;
  float: left;
  top: 2%;
}

.rightDiv {
  width: 49.5%;
  background: grey;
  min-height: 400px;
  float: left;
  left: 1%;
}

.clear:after {
  clear: both;
  display: table;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="dataWrapper leftDiv">test div</div>
<div class="dataWrapper rightDiv"> test</div>
<div class="dataWrapper leftDiv">test div</div>
<div class="dataWrapper rightDiv"> test</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why people downwote questions too much.. I don't find I asked anything wrong here.. Why are people down voting this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.
The dataWrapper::before has a padding-top attribute. 100% padding top will heighten the parent to a square. If you want the div to be half as high as it is wide then choose "padding-top: 50%".

If you need content in your dataWrapper's you can add another div with position absolute.

Hope this helps.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dataWrapper {
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  outline: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.dataWrapper::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

#main {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  transform: skew(0, -3deg);
}

<div id="main">
  <div class="dataWrapper"></div>
  <div class="dataWrapper"></div>
  <div class="dataWrapper"></div>
  <div class="dataWrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer Markus. I need to make this div's align perfectly as shown in the image.

Comment: Hold on dude I'm testing

Comment: @Marcus It's not taking any content after adding a child div with position   absolute

Comment: Got it @Markus.. Thanks for your info

Comment: @jegadeesh My pleasure!